# Webscraping returns nothing when trying to find a div using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to set up a program that would notify me whenever the price of the "Best" flight from HK to New Delhi to Osaka drops. I take Skyscanner's search result page for the ground of my program.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.skyscanner.com.hk/transport/d/hkga/2019-12-28/del/del/2020-01-05/osaa?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&ref=home&locale=en-GB#/'

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
pricebox = soup.find('div', class_= 'Price_mainPriceContainer__1dqsw')
price = pricebox.find('span', class_= 'BpkText_bpk-text__2NHsO BpkText_bpk-text--base__2vfTl BpkText_bpk-text--bold__4yauk').text
```

Well I wanted to locate the first div containing the span that has the price of "Best Flight" wrapped in it so I used find() method to find the div with class attribute 'Price_mainPriceContainer__1dqsw'. However, it returned nothing. I cannot figure out what went wrong.

EDIT: First of all, thank you for all your help. Really appreciate that. In case you haven't realised, I am a super beginner. Anyway, I installed ChromeDriver and Selenium and tried to run the code that @QHarr offered and it returned an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testflight.py", line 6, in <module>
     d = webdriver.Chrome(r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
```

I don't know why this happened. I already relocated the ChromeDriver to /usr/local/bin, installed the ChromeDriver corresponding to my Google Chrome version and the Google Chrome is installed with the right default path.

Comment: Have you tried using **lxml** parser, if not, try like this : `BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')` but you should have installed the lxml using `pip install lxml`

Comment: Also, when I checked your link in the URL source code, I couldn't find the class attribute you provided. So be sure of what you search whether it really exists

Comment: page use JavaScript to add content and BS doesn't run JavaScript. You may use `Selenum` to control web browser which can run JavaScript. OR find url used by JavaScript to get data and use it with `requests.get()`

Comment: @furas it's `Selenium` please do check words accurately because that is going to help others.

Comment: @amrs-tech to late to fix this typo. I write so many comments and answers every day so I'm too tired to read all text :)

Comment: @amrs-tech "Price_mainPriceContainer__1dqsw" appears 13 times when I search it.

Answer (score 1):

As the page is making requests to various partners to find best price there will be a lot of traffic and potentially not a single xhr which you can always address for the best price (theory not tested). I would probably go with selenium and have a wait condition for all results to be in on page then extract the best price

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'path\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://www.skyscanner.com.hk/transport/d/hkga/2019-12-28/del/del/2020-01-05/osaa?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&ref=home&locale=en-GB#/')
WebDriverWait(d,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^=Results_dayViewItems]")))
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[class^=Price_mainPriceContainer] span').text
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code and now I got a new error. I edited it to my post.